# RxJS - Multiple sources for .withLatestFrom

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I want to merge the latest emitted values from multiple Observables, so right now I'm using `.withLatestFrom`. Except, it nests the data together in nested arrays instead of pushing the data into a new array value. Example code below.

Any ideas on how I can retrieve multiple Observable emits using `.withLatestFrom`?

```ts
source0
  .withLatestFrom(source1)
  .withLatestFrom(source2)
  .withLatestFrom(source3)
  .map((data) => { console.log(data) });
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`withLatestFrom` supports multiple observables:

```
.withLatestFrom(source1, source2, source3)
.map((data) => { console.log(data) });

-> [val, value1, value2, value3]
```

It also supports function as it's last parameter, so you can get values other than arrays:

```
observable$
    .withLatestFrom(source1, source2, (val, one, two) => {
        return {val: val, one: one, two: two};
     });
```

Comment: You can wrap the `{}` with `()` then you don't need an explicit return statement : `.withLatestFrom(source1, source2, (val, one, two) => ({ val: val, one: one, two: two  }));`

Answer (score 9):

withLatestFrom accepts multiple observables. so you can write it like:

```
let obs1$ = Rx.Observable.of('a');
let obs2$ = Rx.Observable.of('b');

Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .withLatestFrom(obs1$, obs2$)
  .subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```